# Japanese word meaning "sister" if the position in the family is unknown

Tags: words, word-requests

I am translating the sentence from English into Japanese:

> On Christmas I get toys from my **sister**.

I have no idea if the sister is older or younger than the speaker. So, if I don't want to be guessing, I can use neither 姉　nor 妹. Which word should I use in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: @naruto Thank you! I have read the answers. The person whose answer is accepted says "The ultimate option is to take a shot in the dark." Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, if you are absolutely sure this "sister" won't appear again in the plot, it works :)

Comment: Maybe you could you say 兄弟にもらった? Or 親戚にもらった